# Remote control of Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access

We need to put few touch screens running Ubuntu in front of few restaurants. The idea is that they are connected by wi-fi to internet so we can make the necessary changes from our office and not going there. Also, as the screen will display some information regarding the restaurant, when we log-in, we want to be able to get a separate screen and not interfere with the current one, so there will be no cut in the service. Something like Multi-seat system.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few come to mind but the easiest of which would probably be [VNC](http://www.tightvnc.com).

You can take a look at how to configure it here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC.  This one is also a pretty good resource: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=122402

This will allow you to remotely connect to the machine running Ubuntu or any other Linux for that matter with a full graphical screen.  If you choose to make changes via command line then SSH is your preferred bet.

One thing I would assume you would have to have a firewall in front of these screens with appropriate port forwarding configured.